# TSS returned by K means clustering is always the same

Tags: r, clustering, k-means

I have high dimensional ($m \approx 2k$), high sample (n=140,000) dataset in R that I load into memory run PCA on it (returns $m \approx 400$ components to cover 95% of variance) then I run k means clustering on this dataset. However, even with wildly different number of clusters (from 1 to 1000) I always get the same total sum of squares. Though the cluster assigned to the datapoints I have inspected seem reasonable at first sight (they change seemingly appropriately with the number of clusters.)

So codewise:

```
trans = preProcess(train, method=c('BoxCox','center','scale','pca'))
train_pc = predict(trans, train)
kNumbers = c(1,5,10,15,20,25,100,1000)
for (i in kNumbers) {
    model = kmeans(train_pc, centers=i, nstart=10)
    cat(model$totss + '\n')
}
```

Things I have tried:

- Playing with `iter_max` from 10 to 100 (then usually no warning messages about lack of convergence)
- Increasing the `n_start` (1 to 10)
- Preprocessing the data `BoxCox`, `center`, `scale`

Ultimately, this is just a part of feature engineering so if there is a way to get some generic way of informing the subsequent algorithm of some sort of idea of "big picture" closeness, then I am all up for that as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: `TSS returned by K means clustering is always the same`. Why should it be different? It is WSS what is expected to differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total sum of squares is literally the *total*, every point to every other point. Unless you change the data set, this is not expected to change.

What you are interested in is WCSS, within-cluster sum-of-squares.

Note that this value is expected to be decreasing with the number of clusters. Don't use it for estimating the number of clusters (instead, visualize, analyze, and evaluate your data; don't trust any single number statistic)